# Number of positive integers which have no ones as exponents in their prime factorisation

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Given $n \in \mathbb{N}^+$, define $f(n) := |\{k \in \mathbb{N}^+, k\leq n | k = p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots p_m^{\alpha_m} \;\text{with} \;p_i \;\text{prime and}\;
 \alpha_i \geq 2 \; \forall 1\leq i\leq m\}|$.

How does $f$ behave asymptotically?
By plotting some numerical data I imagine it will be something like $ \sim \sqrt{n}$ but I am not sure how to prove this.

Comment: Logically, it makes some sense to grow like $\sqrt{n}$ because you force all prime factors to have a power of at least $2$.  I'd imagine if you forced them to have a power of at least $k$, they'd grow line $n^\frac1k$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are called  (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerful_number)) powerful numbers, so named by Golomb, while 2-full or square-full are also used. They were initially studied by Erdos and Szekeres.

Indeed we have (shown by Golomb)
$$
cx^{1/2}-3x^{1/3} \leq k(x) \leq c x^{1/2},\quad c=\zeta(3/2)/\zeta(3)=2.173\cdots,
$$
where $k(x)$ is the number of powerful numbers in $[1,x].$